# How Can I Create a OK CANCEL MessageBox with DevExpress MetropolisDark Theme at WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, messagebox

I have a classic OK CANCEL MessageBox that I have given the codes below.How Can I Create a OK CANCEL `MessageBox` with DevExpress MetropolisDark Theme at WPF C#?

C# CODE

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("ARE YOU SURE?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    //LOGIC
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DevExpress WPF suite offers a skinned replacement for the MessageBox class called the [DXMessageBox](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXMessageBox.class). You can use the static [Show method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXMessageBox.Show.overloads) to display a skinned modal message box similar to how you might with the standard .NET MessageBox class.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you can't style the built-in `MessageBox` using any DevExpress themes.

Instead of showing a `MessageBox` you could consider creating and showing a window with buttons that looks like a `MessageBox`. Then you can style the controls in the window however you want. It is either this or forget about the theming.

Comment: This is incorrect, as DevExpress offers a themed MessageBox analog.

Comment: Did you miss the word "built-in"? Styling or using a DXMessageBox will certainly not change the appearance of the built-in MessageBox class. Now, you could use a DXMessageBox or a window as suggested but neither change the appearance of the MessageBox. So I don't see anything in my answer that is "incorrect".

Comment: You're right in that I misread the part about styling the "built-in" MessageBox, but it's still incorrect to state that the only options are to build a window with buttons or forgo theming altogether.

Comment: "_It is either this or forget about the theming._" kind of implies just that.